# Hide posts having children terms when display posts by category in edit.php

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin

I have a custom post type called `"ttc_infobit"` that belongs to a custom taxonomy named `"ttc_catalogue"`. This taxonomy is a hierarchical.

When I filter posts in `edit.php` by this taxonomy, I want to show only posts having the currently selected term, and not its children.

For example if my url is:

`/wp-admin/edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=ttc_infobit&action=-1&m=0&lang=el&admin_page_template&ttc_catalogue=77&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1`

WordPress will shows posts having `ttc_catalogue` with id 77 but also shows posts having `ttc_catalogue` with ids 101 and 102 that are children ot the 77.

How can I filter `edit.php` to show only items with id=77?

Answer (score 1):

By default when you run a query for a hierarchical taxonomy term, WordPress also returns post from its children. This happen on backend and on frontend as well.

[`'tax_query'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) argument has an argument `'include_children'` that was introduced for the scope, from Codex:

> **include_children** (boolean) Whether or not to include children for hierarchical taxonomies.
>   Defaults to true.

So you should run a tax query to set that param to false, however is **not** possible run a tax query from a url, but you can act on `'pre_get_posts'` and set it.

See inline comments for further informations:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
  if ( // being sure the query is the right one
    ! is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query()
    || ! ( $term = $query->get('ttc_catalogue') )
  ) return;
  // being sure the page is the right one
  $s = get_current_screen();
  if ( $s->id !== 'edit-ttc_infobit' ) return; 
  // prepare tax query
  $tax_query = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'ttc_catalogue',
    'terms' => array( $term ),
    'field' => is_numeric( $term ) ? 'id' : 'slug',
    'include_children' => FALSE
  );
  // set tax query
  $query->set( 'tax_query', array( $tax_query ) );
  // unset 'plain' ttc_catalogue argument
  $query->set( 'ttc_catalogue', '' );
});
```

Comment: Very insightful. Actually in my 3.7.1 (I use that because of a bug in 3.8.1), there is an action in query.php (core) `do_action( 'parse_tax_query', $this );` That needs to be updated (see trac https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18703). It solved it successfully, but I will also try yours to see if it doesn't need to edit the core file.

Comment: @Panagiotis you should not use 'parse_tax_query' for the scope as **dd32** said in that ticket.